# AngularJS: Módulos, Controllers

Tags: angularjs, controller

Estoy trabajando con AngularJS y me han surgido algunas dudas:
Un módulo debe incluir los controllers de la aplicación que estoy desarrollando, normalmente, se crea el módulo y se añade los controller en el mismo archivo

en app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module(mainApp,[]);
mainApp.controller('controller1', fucntion($scope){});
mainApp.controller('controller2', fucntion($scope){});
```

pero ¿si quiero crearlos en otros archivos?
En todos los foros que he consultado, crean un módulo para cada controller.

En controler1.js

```
angular.module(mainApp, []).controller('controller1' function($scope){})
```

En controler2.js

```
angular.module(mainApp, []).controller('controller2' function($scope){})
```

¿Se crea un módulo para cada controller, o se carga el módulo existente? ¿Es una buena práctica?

Gracias de antemano.